# Get previous day date in MySQL format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to get count of previous day records from database.

I am using following method

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day'));
$users = 'SELECT Count(*) FROM users where date="'.$date.'"';
```

This is show count 0 as date format in database is (Y-m-d H:i:s).

Thanks.

Comment: Downvoted with regret, partly for requesting urgency from volunteers, and also because you received three answers on the same day and did not vote, accept or comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could just do

```
select count(*) from users where to_days(date) = (to_days(now()) - 1);
```

This is useful if your date column is a datetime - we're just converting to a day number and checking how many records have yesterdays day number.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it will help you

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE date = (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider asking MYSQL itself about it, so that PHP doesn't have to compute it (and it is likely to be faster) :

`SELECT Count(*) FROM users WHERE date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`